# How to handle large number of rows in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like `comment` with 100k + rows and it is increasing day by day

Frequently I have need to select records form this table

```
+----+---------+-------
| id | comment | type |
+----+---------+------+
| 1    aaa       photo|
| 2    bbb       phono|
| 3    ccc       video|
| 4    ddd       video|
| 5    eee       story|
 ...   ...       ...
```

Is it will be faster if I create 3 tables except 1 table?

as

```
comment_photo
+----+---------+
| id | comment |
+----+---------+
| 1    aaa     |
| 2    bbb     |
 ...   ...    


comment_video
+----+---------+
| id | comment |
+----+---------+
| 1    ccc     |
| 2    ddd     |
 ...   ...   


comment_story
+----+---------+
| id | comment |
+----+---------+
| 1    eee     |
| 2    fff     |
 ...   ...
```

Comment: Are you selecting your data by `id` or by `comment`/`type` too? You can always try to ad some indexes. Everything depends on your queries.

Comment: Normalization of the schema is always a good approach, along with indexing.

Comment: Selecting data by item_id and type and this is indexes

Comment: Normalize then by adding `types` table and in comments put `type_id` column instead of `type`

Comment: Is your `comments` (original table, all in one place) table referring to some entity? (i.e. to which comment does belong)

Answer (score 1):

Making tables `comment_photo`, `comment_video` isn't a good idea. What if you will have another type in future? Next table?

Much better will be adding table `comment_type`:

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 1    photo  |
| 2    video  |
| 3    story  |
 ...   ...
```

And then change `comment` into:

```
+----+---------+---------
| id | comment | type_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 1    aaa       1       |
| 2    bbb       1       |
| 3    ccc       2       |
| 4    ddd       2       |
| 5    eee       3       |
 ...   ...       ...
```

Also remember about well planned indexes. Try to [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) your queries and remember - nested loops are your enemies.

Comment: To add to this good answer, if you have large amounts of data you want to add indexes (as mentioned). In this specific case you would add an index to the type_id columns so that you do an index seek when filtering on type_id and not a table scan which would go through your whole table. You will most likely have a user_id column or something to that affect would would also improve performance with an index.